# Onion архитектура: правильно ли подключать к проекту Business слой Infrastructure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, архитектура

На метаните есть пример onion архитектуры. Возник вопрос по данной архитектуре. Там в примере создаётся слой infrastructure.Business и к этому проекту подключаются ссылки в domain.core и Services.Interfaces.
А считается ли нормальным подключать к слою infrastructure.Business, слой Infrastructure.Data и что бы у инфраструктуры бизнеса был доступ к контексту данных приложения и соответсвенно класса unit of work, т.е. работа напрямую с базой? Или же это плохой тон для данной архитектуры?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это структура моего приложения на данный момент.

Вот конкретный проект отвечающий за получения данных из бд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс UnitOfWork:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        private Context db = new Context();

        private ClientRepository clientRepository;

        public ClientRepository Clients
        {
            get
            {
                if (clientRepository == null)
                    clientRepository = new ClientRepository(db);
                return clientRepository;
            }
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        private bool disposed = false;

        public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposed)
                db.Dispose();
            disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

Репозиторий клиента:

```
public class ClientRepository : IRepository<Client>
    {
        private Context db;

        public ClientRepository(Context context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Client> GetAll()
        {
            return db.Clients.ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetFieldsValue(Func<Client, Boolean> predWhere, Func<Client, dynamic> predSelect)
        {
            return db.Clients.Where(predWhere).Select(predSelect).ToList();
        }

        public Client Get(int id)
        {
            return db.Clients.Find(id);
        }

        public void Create(Client client)
        {
            db.Clients.Add(client);
        }

        public void Update(Client client)
        {
            db.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            Client client = db.Clients.Find(id);
            if (client != null)
                db.Clients.Remove(client);
        }
    }
```

Доменная модель клиента из проекта Domain.Core:

```
public class Client
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Фамилия")]
        public string CSurname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Имя")]
        public string CName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Отчество")]
        public string CPatronymic { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Логин")]
        public string Login { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Пароль")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "E-meil")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        public Client()
        {
            Orders = new List<Order>();
        }
    }
```

Интерфейс репозитория:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        T Get(int id);
        IEnumerable<dynamic> GetFieldsValue(Func<T, Boolean> predWhere, Func<T, dynamic> predSelect);
        void Create(T item);
        void Update(T item);
        void Delete(int id);
    }
```

Comment: Вот хорошая [лекция](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lwCVE_XgqI&t=695s) на эту тему.

Comment: @Bulson Мне очень нравится подход, предложенный в видео, поэтому часто упоминаю его. Однако пришло время процитировать один из комментариев под ним: "There is a dependency injection to an Entity Framework DbContext. *The Application Layer has a high dependency to the persistence Layer*. I know this is addressed on 29:45, but still *not a purely "clean" application layer.*"

Answer (score 2):

Я не буду прятаться за тем, что "норма" бывает разная: раз вы хотите "правильную" onion архитектуру — то будем и говорить о ней.

> Зависимости в исходном коде должны быть направлены внутрь, в сторону
>   высокоуровневых политик.

По определению, модуль является "верхним" уровнем если он сам не зависит от других модулей. Модули нижнего уровня — те, которые зависят от большого числа других модулей и чем больше модулей от которого есть зависимости, тем ниже модуль в иерархии.

Так вот как только вы захотите, чтобы ваш высокоуровневый модуль подключал/знал о нижних модулях — вы нарушаете принцип, согласно которому модули нижних уровней должны зависеть от модулей верхних уровней, а не наоборот.

В бизнес-слое нужно знать что есть слой инфраструктурный, но инфраструктура - это очень изменчивый модуль (чем больше изменчивость — тем ниже модуль), поэтому вышележащие слои от него не должны зависеть.

Всё вышеописанное можно более детально прочитать у Роберта Мартина в книге "Чистая архитектура", одна из must read книг для разработчика. Там как раз и будет показано откуда берётся принцип инверсии зависимостей (для архитектуры на уровне класса), рассказано о стабильных абстракциях и конкретных компонентах, полных и неполных архитектурных границах и как они выглядят, а также показан принцип на уровне крупных модулей. Очень, очень рекомендую прочитать эту книгу.

Как же делать "по науке"? Объявляйте в проектах высокого уровня интерфейсы, реализуйте их в нижележащих проектах,  при старте приложения объявляйте как вы будете резолвить зависимости.

Comment: AK получается если добавить ссылку к слою Infrastructure.Business на слой слой Infrastructure.Data в котором есть доступ к бд, это сделает слой бизнеса более низким? Но ведь по сути и то и то слой инфраструктуры, или я не прав?

Comment: @Андрей В слое инфраструктуры у вас два проекта? Значит, один из них - более высокого уровня, второй - более низкого. Могло бы быть и три и пять, это дело бы не поменяло. Почитайте про инверсию зависимостей в книге: слой низкого уровня _вызывает_ код из более высокого уровня, но модуль высокого уровня не должен подключать код из модулей более низкого уровня. Разрыв этот делается именно через объявление интерфейса и его реализацию.

Comment: AK, да 2 проекта, но получается у меня в слое бизнесс логики не будет прямого доступа к базе данных, и  на слой бизнесс логики придётся передавать уже готовые модели или просто данные из базы, а у меня проблема с тем что нужно бы достать данные из базы на слое бизнеса, и вот из за этого появился этот вопрос.

Comment: AK живой пример моей проблемы, это то что есть форма входа в систему. Ввожу я логин и пароль. И встаёт делемма, где доставать пользователя с этим логином и паролем, и проверять правильность пароля и логина? Сразу в контроллере? Мне показалось что контроллер не должен за это отвечать. Тогда далее вопрос. Если делать интерфейс бизнес логики а далее реализацию в слое infrastructure.business тогда придётся передавать туда из контроллера уже самого клиента, а вот если бы например на слое бизнеса был бы доступ к бд, тогда бы я там мог достать клиента и проверить по введённым параметрам.

Comment: @Андрей Пример на вход в систему не из этой оперы. Если вы почитаете литературу, то во многих правильных книгах говорится, что аутентификация/авторизация - это вещь сквозная для всего приложения, она может присутствовать в каком-то виде НА ВСЕХ слоях приложения. Другой пример сквозной функциональности - это логирование. Поэтому этот пример давайте не обсуждать в этом вопросе, хорошо? По той фразе где "да 2 проекта" - а давайте вы дополните вопрос принтскрином структуры проекта и более расширенно опишете пример на доставание данных из базы. Прям с классами, чтобы было конкретно.

Comment: AK, хорошо, и последняя тогда точка по авторизации, это не плохо если я буду доставать пользователя и проверять прям в контроллере?

Comment: А по поводу структуры, она сейчас такая как в примере на метаните, но я приведу пример в вопросе.

Comment: AK я описал пример структуры в вопросе.

Comment: @Андрей Посмотрел структуру. Да, значит я всё понял устройство проекта правильно по вашему описанию словами. В правильной чистой архитектуре такого быть не должно, в менее строгой - пренебрегают. В качестве примера посмотрите видео по ссылке Bullson: там очень простая и эффективная структура приложения, которой удобно на практике пользоваться, при этом она не совсем "чистая" в строгих терминах. Вопрос, какую архитектуру выбирать - это уже ваша оценка рисков проекта.

Comment: AK спасибо большое за комментарии. Посмотрю видео. Поразбираюсь, Почитаю книгу которую посоветовали. Надеюсь она есть в свободном доступе в интернете? Или только покупать?